# Quadratics and roots

Tags: roots, quadratics

Consider the equation (E): $$x^2 - (m+1)x+m+4=0$$ where $m$ is a real parameter 
determine $m$ so that $2$ is a root of (E) and calculate the other root.

This is the question.

What I did was basically this:

Let the sum of root 1 and root 2 be $S$ and their product $P$
Let $x_2 = a ; x_1=2$(given)

1. $S=m+1$

   $m+1=2+a$

   $m-a=1$
2. $P=m+4$

   $m+4=2a$

   $m-2a=-4$

then these 2 equations form a system whose answers would be $m=6$ and $a=5$.

Is it possible to determine $m$ so that $x^2−(m+1)x+m+4<0$ for all $x \in  \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I just want to know how to solve it cause I am not sure I solved it correctly

Comment: Why not just put $x=2$ to start off with and determine $m$. Then from the sum of the roots the other root is $m-1$ - at least you can use this to check whether your method has given you the right answer.

Comment: If we want $x=2$ to be a root, substituting that into the quadratic should give us 0

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: See my edits to understand a little of how to make your posts more readable.

Comment: thanks @JohnHughes

Comment: This approach will certainly work, but the suggestions of @MarkBennet and JihoonKang are simpler.

Comment: thanks @MarkBennet yup it worked the answers are correct. I have no idea why I used such a long method when I could have just replaced the x with 2 like you said

Comment: I have changed $x1, x2$ to $x_1, x_2$ - but note that you don't need these - you are using different names for the roots in different places. If you do this with more complex calculations you will confuse yourself. You could just say "let the roots be $2$ (given) and $a$. The product of the roots $2a=m+4$ and the sum of the roots $2+a=m+1$

Comment: it does get a bit confusing at times @MarkBennet

Comment: A quadratic, monic polynomial $p(x)$ cannot be negative for all values of $x$ since $\lim_{x\to \pm\infty} p(x)=+\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Divide the given polynomial by $x-2$.

This yields the quotient $x-m+1$ and the remainder $-m+6$.

Then $m=6$ and $x=5.$

Answer (score 1):

If $2$ is a root of $x^2-(m+1)x+(m+4)=0$ then

\begin{align}
&2=\frac{(m+1)\pm\sqrt[\;2]{(m+1)^2-4\cdot (m+4)}}{2}
\\
\Leftrightarrow&
4=(m+1)\pm \sqrt[\;2]{m^2-2m-15}
\\
\Leftrightarrow&
-m+3 =\pm \sqrt[\;2]{m^2-2m-15}
\\
\Leftrightarrow&
(-m+3)^2 =\left(\pm \sqrt[\;2]{m^2-2m-15}\right)^2
\\
\Leftrightarrow&
(-m+3)^2 =\left|m^2-2m-15\right|
\end{align}
**Case 1:** If $m^2-2m-15=(m+3)(m-5)> 0$ then we have 
\begin{align}
(-m+3)^2 =+(m^2-2m-15),& \hspace{1cm} m<-3 \mbox{ or } m>5\\
m^2-6m+9 = m^2-2m-15,  & \hspace{1cm} m<-3 \mbox{ or } m>5\\
-4m = -24,  & \hspace{1cm} m<-3 \mbox{ or } m>5\\
 m = 6,  & \hspace{1cm} m<-3 \mbox{ or } m>5\\
\end{align}

**Case 2:** If $m^2-2m-15=(m+3)(m-5)< 0$ then we have 
\begin{align}
(-m+3)^2 =-(m^2-2m-15),&\hspace{1cm} -3<m<5\\
m^2-6m+9 =-m^2+2m+15,&\hspace{1cm} -3<m<5\\
2m^2-8m-6 =0,&\hspace{1cm} -3<m<5\\
m^2-4m-3 =0,&\hspace{1cm} -3<m<5\\
m=\frac{4\pm \sqrt{4^2-4\cdot 1\cdot (-3)}}{2\cdot 1},&\hspace{1cm} -3<m<5\\
m=2\pm \sqrt{7},&\hspace{1cm} -3<m<5\\
\end{align}
In this case there is no integer solution.

**Case 3:** If $m^2-2m-15=(m+3)(m-5)=0$ then we have 
\begin{align}
(-m+3)^2 =0,& \hspace{1cm} m=-3 \mbox{ or } m=5\\
    m=3,& \hspace{1cm} m=-3 \mbox{ or } m=5\\
\end{align}
But it's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is correct, but you should use more standard variable names for your roots.

Use the [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas). $(x-x_1)(x-x_2)=x^2-(x_1+x_2)x+x_1x_2$

Comparison with your equation yields:
$$x_1+x_2=m+1$$
$$x_1x_2=m+4$$
$$\text{subtraction}\implies x_1x_2-(x_1+x_2)=4-1$$

Now, plug in $x_1=2$.

Answer (score 0):

plugging $2$ into the given equation we get $$4-2(m+1)+m+4=0$$ or $$m=6$$
and for $m=6$ we get
$$x^2-7x+10=0$$